# Set column format to boolean (TRUE FALSE) in ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, closedxml

I am using ClosedXML to generate an Excel file which is partly filled in. One of the columns has boolean values. I would like to display these boolean values as TRUE / FALSE. I noticed that `Column.Style.NumberFormat` can be used to format numbers as scientific notation etc. However, there is no suitable value in `XLPredefinedFormat` for booleans. How to set data type / format of the entire column to show TRUE / FALSE instead of 1 / 0?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [How do I make Excel recognise TRUE or FALSE text as boolean values?](https://superuser.com/questions/651038/how-do-i-make-excel-recognise-true-or-false-text-as-boolean-values)

Comment: The following may also be helpful. Use MS Excel to create the document you desire. Then use the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) to look at the _.xlsx_ file.

Comment: Excel Booleans make programmers weep. There is a Boolean type, but no Boolean format. Excel Booleans look useful and tempting, but in the end, they are mostly useless

Comment: @Flydog57 They are very useful. For example they're the primary input type for the second parameter of the FILTER function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific format for boolean types. Just ensure the underlying values are boolean (not 1s and 0s) and format the range as `General`.